# Get the latest n reachable tags in Git sorted

Tags: git

`git describe` retrieves the latest reachable tag.

`git tag --list` retrieves all the tags.

I need something close to git describe but to retrieve the **N latest tags**, N=1,2,3... **reachable**, **sorted** by creation date.

Comment: @evolutionxbox The OP obviously discovered `git describe` which is related. If this question duplicates another, please mark it as such. IMHO, this is a clear and valid question.

Comment: I tried to retrieve all the tag list and sort by date reverse, but this includes tags that are not in my current commit path, so this could lead to errors. Appart from that I read the git tag and git describe documentation and nothing seems to be helpful for my purpose

Comment: @blubb I don't recall stating that this question is invalid or a duplicate? Showing effort to solving an issue will definitely help.

Comment: @evolutionxbox maybe I can explain my purpose to maybe find a different way to achieve the same. I didn't do it at the beginning to avoid unuseful information: I want to get the latest tags to apply some algorithm to deduce the next tag. The naming convention we use is a little bit complicated, so just using the latest tag name is not good enough to deduce the next tag, that's why I need a little bit more of information :)

Comment: Maybe since the tags are kept in `.git/refs/tags` then you can use date modified or date created to sort them? Also, aren't tags reachable by default, since they are one of the factors which make commits reachable?

Comment: Not all flavours of tags keep track of  their creation date...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

`git tag --sort=-creatordate | tail -n <N>`

or in reverse order:

`git tag --sort=creatordate | tail -n <N>`

Comment: Sorry :( but this is one of the things I already tried, according to the initial question; this is not doing the trick because it's considering the whole repository up to the current point in the commit loaded in the workspace, no matter the branch. Thus, it's considering tags not reachable in the current branch. If you compare this command with "git describe" you'll see differences: the last tag considered by "describe" is not the same as the one considered by "tag". Nevertheless, I appreciate your time and your help ;)